# AWS Static S3 Website won't load in IE

Tags: amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, microsoft-edge, static-site

I have a static website hosted in AWS S3. The website loads correctly in Chrome but IE (11 and Edge) decides to download files when I try to navigate to the site instead of loading the pages normally. Some further details:

- webpage files do not have a file extension, they are of the form "index", "contact" etc.
- cloudfront is in use
- All files are public in the bucket
- webpage files are set to:

  - Content-Language: html
  - Content-Type: text\html

It was working in IE previously so I am unsure what the change is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your [Content Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) is wrong; the slash is in the wrong direction. When I checked the http response headers, I see:

```
Content-Type: text\html
```

Try changing that to:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

It appears Chrome will accept it, but Edge does not recognize it, and therefore downloads the site. I think Edge thinks its text only content.